# Firebase: Found conflicting getters for name for Abstract class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

BaseItem.class:

```
public abstract class BaseItem{
    @Exclude
    public abstract BaseItemDescription getDescription();
}
```

BaseItemDescription.class:

```
public static class BaseItemDescription{
   String title;
}
```

MyItem.class:

```
    public class MyItem extends BaseItem {
       MyItemDescription description;

       @Override
       public MyItemDescription getDescription(){
          return description;
       }

      public static class MyItemDescription extends BaseItemDescription{
        //other fields
      }
    }
```

I added `@Exclude` to abstract method, but the error still occurs
Error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getDescription
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzm.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzl.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzl.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzl.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
```